# Finding Root of an Equation with Variables Dependent on Each other

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Sorry for the title.  I'm sure there is better terminology.  I'd be interested to here what that terminology is haha.

Here is my problem:

```
If x < 40, y = 0.01
If x > 40, y = 0.02
If x > 50, y = 0.03

0 = -1000 + (x-30–[x*y])*50
```

Solve for $x$ and $y$.

This is a breakeven revenue equation that would normally only include $x$ (price) but now also includes $y$ (a royalty % of price).

I need to do solve this in a way that can be accomplished programmatically with R or VBA.

It was suggested to me that I could make a guess for $y$, solve for $x$, and then again solve for $x$ and so on until I came to an answer for each.  Would it not be an infinite loop?

Comment: is this homework? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've found $x=\frac{50}{0.97}\approx 51.54639,y=0.03$ if you mean

$y=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0.01 \\ 
0.02 \\ 
0.03
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
\text{if} \\ 
\text{if} \\ 
\text{if}
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
x\leq 40 \\ 
40<x\leq 50 \\ 
x>50
\end{array}
\right. $

and

$0=-1000+50\left( x-30-\left( xy\right) \right)
=-2500+50x-50xy\Leftrightarrow y=\frac{x-50}{x}$.

Comment: Nope not homework, real work.  Thanks guys I got it.  That was much easier than expected.  In the end I made a VBA function to calculate y, and a Newton-Raphson function in R though RExcel to calculate x.  Didn't even need to code anything iterative. Excel handled the circular reference automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said - the best way to solve this would be to loop over all values of $y$, solve for $x$, and then see if $x$ falls within the correct bin. For instance, if you try $y=0.01$, you'll find that $x>50$, so that cannot be a solution. There is no infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the function:
$$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rr} 50(x-30-.01 \cdot x) - 1000 & : x < 40 \\ 50(x-30-.02 \cdot x) - 1000 & : x > 40 \land x \le 50 \\ 50(x-30-.03 \cdot x) - 1000 & : x > 50 \\ \end{array} \right.
$$

Which we can simply to
$$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rr} 50\left(\frac{99x}{100}-30\right) - 1000 & : x < 40 \\ 50\left(\frac{98x}{100}-30\right) - 1000 & : x > 40 \land x \le 50 \\ 50\left(\frac{97x}{100}-30\right) - 1000 & : x > 50 \\ \end{array} \right.
$$

We could try setting each statement equal to zero, solve for $x$ and see if $x$ falls within the conditions for that given equation

To do this programmatically it might be best to look over at stackoverflow